# Complex powers question, raising i to the power of i

Tags: complex-analysis

I am confused as to what $$i^{i}$$ looks like. I followed the procedure our prof described and got $$e^{i\log i}=e^{\log i+2ki\pi }=e^{-2k\pi (\cos(\log i)+i\sin(\log i))}.$$

However, $$i^{i}=e^{-\pi/2}$$

Is it the same thing or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Use $i = e^{i \pi / 2}$ to evaluate the logarithm in the middle.

Comment: You might wish to define $a^b=e^{b\operatorname{Log}(a)}, where $\operatorname{Log}$ denotes the principal log.

Answer (score 2):

There's no unambiguous definition for complex logarithm, hence several answers are legitimate.